# Как завершить вызов через 10 секунд после поднятия трубки?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile-development

Совершаю вызов таким образом

```
public void OnClick(View v)
        {    
        if (!userNum.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            no = userNum.Text.ToString();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
            callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + no));

            callIntent.SetPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
            StartActivity(callIntent);

        }
}
```

Как его завершить?

Comment: может быть `Finish();` ?

Comment: мне кажется, он полностью завершает работу приложения) или может Вы подскажите, куда правильно будет это записать, чтоб после того, как мы определим, что разговор начался, прошло 10 секунд и разговор завершился?

Comment: `Finish()` завершает свою `Activity`. В Андроид SDK нет легального способа завершить звонок. Можно лишь попытаться сделать "хак", но никакой гарантии работоспособности на всех устройствах, особенно с Андроид 9. Если есть желание попытаться, посмотрите ответ на en-so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17538956